# Values of associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have an associative array with two keys

```
$miarray = array(
    array('factor' => $textof[1],    'valor' => $i1),
    array('factor' => $textof[2],    'valor' => $i2),
    array('factor' => $textof[3],    'valor' => $i3),
    array('factor' => $textof[4],    'valor' => $i4),
    array('factor' => $textof[5],    'valor' => $i5),
    array('factor' => $textof[6],    'valor' => $i6),
    array('factor' => $textof[7],    'valor' => $i7),
    array('factor' => $textof[8],    'valor' => $i8),
    array('factor' => $textof[9],    'valor' => $i9),
    array('factor' => $textof[10],    'valor' => $i10),
);
```

the first key has text and the second key has numeric values. i want to order the array  by de second key in ascending order and the add each pair to a variable that will be echoed at the end of the php file.

to sort i use the following

```
array_multisort(array_column($miarray, 'valor'), SORT_ASC, $miarray);
```

and to access each pair

```
foreach ($miarray as $optionArray){ 
$pr .="$optionArray[\"factor\"] - $optionArray[\"valor\"]<br>";
}
```

nevertheless i get error

[20-Nov-2018 17:58:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

i have seen many examples but all use print to show the resulting array.
thanks for helping.

Comment: use single columns inside the string?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky i get the same error with simple cuotation '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are accessing array keys inside double quotes you can leave out the escaped quotes and do it like this:

```
$pr .= "$optionArray[factor] - $optionArray[valor]<br>";
```

Alternately you can concat the desired values:

```
$pr .= $optionArray['factor'] . ' - ' . $optionArray['valor'] . '<br>';
```

Either one of those should work, but referencing the keys inside of double quotes the way you have it is the reason for your error.

Read more about how php parses variables here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: The code they provided would not have triggered a syntax error. Granted, it wouldn't have worked either, but their error will not be resolved by this change.

Comment: @miken32 - of course it would.  here's the error: http://codepad.org/i45ZFCtg

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. I assumed since the quotes were escaped it would just treat the value literally, but I guess the parser realizes it's inside an array index and complains.

Comment: I tried posting a working codepad but apparently it uses older php where array_column is not a function yet... here's the working version on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/jCP2D